# Matrix Transformation - Using matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

How do I use matrix multiplication to find the reflection of (-1,2) about the x axis, y axis and the line y=x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of those is a linear transformation, so can be represented by matrix multiplication. Let's say the first one, reflection about the $x$-axis. Say, it is represented by some matrix $A$. Then,
$$
A \pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{1\\0}
\text{ and }
A \pmatrix{0\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\-1},
$$
so
$$
A \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1} = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & -1}
$$
Do you now know what $A$ is? What happens when you compute
$$
A \pmatrix{-1\\2}?
$$

Can you do the others the same way?

Comment: Helpful, thanks.